# Login Page - Detecting the user type and lead him to their main pages

Tags: php, database, forms, authentication

I have a basic login page. I currently use a users table in which I have username and password columns. My system has 3 types of users: principal, academic director and lecturer. The truth is that I created table for each of the users. How can I detect them and direct them to the their main pages? For example for the lecturer user I have 2 colummns lecusername and lecpasswprd.

```
  <html>
  <head><h1>Login Page</h1>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <center>


     <form action = "login.php" method = "POST">

       Username: <input type="text" name="username"> <br /><br/>
       Password: <input type="password" name="password"> <br /><br/>

     <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">


     </form>

 </center>
 </body>
 </html>

      <?php

       $error ='';

       require('connect.php');

       $username = @$_POST['username'];
       $password = @$_POST['password'];


      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {
            if($username && $password)
            {
                 $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password= '".$password."'");
                 $rows = mysql_num_rows($check);


            if(mysql_num_rows($check)!=0)
            {
                 session_start();
                 header("location:/main.php");
                 exit();
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Couldn't find username.";

            }
       }
     else
     {
           echo "Please fill all the fields.";
     }

  }
 ?>
```

Comment: For one thing, you're outputting before header.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I don't get it, can you please explain it more?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, and you'll see what I mean. Plus, `@` symbols suppress errors.

Comment: You're welcome. So, put `<?php session_start(); ?><html>
  <head><h1>Login Page</h1>.....` at the top of your page, followed by the rest of your code and removing `session_start();` where you have it now.

Comment: To answer your question now; you'd need to add a `while($row...` loop, then using something like `if($row['said_column'] == "principal"){...}` inside that loop.

Comment: Btw, you are storing a hash, rather than plain text passwords, *right?* Or, is this for learning purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table should have another Column defined as userType.

The Select statement should return that column.

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT userType 
                      FROM users 
                      WHERE username='".$username."' 
                      AND password= '".$password."'");
```

Now you should read what is the userType

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_row($check);

if($rows[0] == "admin")
{
  session_start();
             header("location:/admin.php");
}
```

Comment: A bit vague, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @Fred -ii- yes it is!